# Is it necessary to learn how to prove Mathematical theorems as a CS Student?

Tags: logic, proof-techniques, discrete-mathematics, propositional-logic

I've just started my undergraduate course and have tried my hands on MIT's OpenCourseWare on Discrete Math on Logic and Proofs. There was a particular question asking to prove Cantor's Theorem:

> **Problem 4.** If a set, $A$, is finite, then $|A| < 2^{|A|} = |\cal P(A)|$, and so there is no surjection from set $A$ to its powerset. Show that this is still true if $A$ is infinite. *Hint:* Remember Russell's paradox and consider $\{x \in A \mid x \notin f(x)\}$ where $f$ is such a surjection.

My question is: am I expected to prove these math theorems and should I focus on my proving skills (because they are proving to be quite difficult for me at the moment)? Do they make me a better problem solver in later courses such as Data Structures and Algorithms?

Comment: All your theory coursework will involve proofs.

Comment: Computer scientists know their program is correct via proofs. Hobbyist coders guess their program is correct via trial-and-error.

Comment: @Billiska And professional programmers almost never prove their programs correct.

Comment: @Billiska I see where you're coming from. But proving Russel's Paradox and when a loop ends seem to differ in rigor. But I'm not entirely sure since I've barely scratched the surface of discrete maths.

Comment: @Xuan Proving when a loop ends is typically far *harder* than proving Russel's paradox.

Comment: There are some things you will do in your coursework that you will never do again unless you end up back in academia. On the other hand, even if you don't use them once you are out of school since they are necessary to complete school, it would be best to be good enough at them. As for proofs, I haven't seen much use for those in my software development career. And most of the decisions I have to make are sufficiently ambiguous with poor information such that heuristics and muddling through works out well enough. Program proof of correction is for software analyzers in my opinion.

Comment: All (good enough) computer science students should be able to prove such theorems; what these proofs involve is exactly proof techniques (and basic discrete math concepts essential for CS). If you don't have proof skills to tackle such problems, when you go into a theoretical CS textbook, e.g., Sipser, CLRS, TaPL, you'll get lost in the exercises very soon.

Comment: I think there are no useful answers here. For any given course of studies, check the curriculum. If you want a debate about curriculua, this is not the place. Closing as opinion-based.

Comment: What does it mean to "prove a paradox"?

Comment: @AndrejBauer to ascertain the validity of the paradox proposed?

Comment: @Xuan: Ah, you mean to show it really is a pardox? That's rather dangerous, what if mathematics disappears in a puff of illogical smoke? Anyhow, at a slightly more serious level, offering paradoxes as examples of things to be proved is not as good as offering ordinary theorems.

Answer (score 3):

Writing computer programs that work *is* a theorem proving activity. Full stop.

Comment: I would say that's not a common point of view. It's like saying that writing computer programs *is* a creative artistic activity, so painting and art appreciation are important for computer science. I feel cheated now that I never took an art history class.

Comment: While my point of view is similar due to Curry-Howard-Lambek correspondence, I think the way you phrased it leaves holes --- a statement maybe true despite there being no known proof. In the same way, a program may work without writer knowing why.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: you are forgetting one thing: the correctness of a program is an objective property. The theorem to be proven is "this programs fulfills its specification". For instance "this program computes the square root of all naturals less than 2^31", which is a mathematical fact. Nothing to do with "how elegant!"

Comment: @Billiska: this writer must be fired. You don't use programs that work by accident. (With one exception: you can use a program for the input values that are known to work, by testing, even if you don't know why. This is because the test *proved* it correct for the given input.)

Comment: @YvesDaoust In practice the first obstacle is getting a specification that is sufficiently precise to enable any kind of proof. There are very few pieces of nontrivial software that have such a specification.

Comment: @adrianN: it's the job of the programmer to formalize the specifications and turn them to a provable theorem (even if this is implicit). Programming languages are formal systems.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I agree with you in principle, but in practice the implementation is the specification and nobody proves any nontrivial property.

Comment: @adrianN: I use to practice "A Method of Programming by Edsger W. Dijkstra et al." and I doubt to be the only one. Besides this, writing a program is by no means a different intellectual activity than proving a theorem. I recently acquired "H. S. Hacker's Delight by Warren Jr", for those who program with bare hands. It is stuffed with proofs. It has to.

Comment: Finding a correct solution is harder than proving correctness of existing solution. Programming is exactly finding a solution.

Comment: @rus9384: programming is writing a correct program, don't be stupid.

Comment: How rude! Why do you think that *writing* ***correct*** program is easier than *checking* correctness of written one? It definitely isn't.

Comment: @rus9384: I don't know where you heard me say that ???

Comment: Okay, misworded. Writing correct program is harder than proving correctness of given algorithm. You say that proof of correctness is enough, but it's not.

Comment: @rus9384: mh, don't know what difference you make between program and algorithm. Let us stop here.

Answer (score 2):

There are several different ways to answer your question.

First, in the particular course you are taking now, part of the material is mathematical proofs. In order to succeed in this course, you need to be able to prove mathematical theorems. There are several reasons for this requirement:

- Some more advanced classes also involve proving theorems.
- The concept of proof and mathematical validity is important even if you don't expect to actively prove theorems. You need to understand the difference between a heuristic algorithm and an algorithm which is *guaranteed* to always work efficiently.
- Programming is an abstract pursue, and requires a certain way of thought. Mathematics is one way to develop this way of thought, since it forces you to think in abstract terms.

Second, while more advance proofs do involve a lot of problem solving, in this particular problem you are handed out the solution, and your task is to convert the hint into a formal proof (in the sense of your class). At this stage of your class, you are not required to be able to create completely new proofs. Rather, the emphasis is on you understanding *what* is a mathematical proof and *how* it is written. Later on you might be given more creative tasks.

Third, the course you're taking will also teach you basic mathematical concepts that might be useful for you in the future. For example, one of the topics you are taught is propositional logic. You could encounter propositional logic in database theory, verification, and elsewhere. The only way to understand such an abstract concept is to play with it, and the way we play with concepts in mathematics is by proving simple statements.

Fourth, you mention that proving theorems is hard for you at the moment. This is why you're taking this class. One goal of the course is to teach you how to prove theorems. You might find it hard, but if the course goes slowly enough, you will eventually find it easy, and will have gained an invaluable skill. In a similar vein, you might have encountered the jump in difficulty level from high school to undergraduate studies. It requires some adjustment, but eventually you will gain the relevant studying skills.

Answer (score 2):

Computer Science as it's taught in universities has a large overlap with applied maths. If you want to succeed in your coursework you have to be able to prove mathematical theorems. A strong foundation in maths is required to do original research (or even understand existing results!) in many fields of computer science. Universities traditionally prepare their students for research.

This is very different from working as a software engineer, where mathematical skills are almost completely unnecessary. You can write great, useful software without understanding basic proof techniques. Almost all software is incredibly mundane when viewed from a science point of view. The hard part in software engineering usually is taming complexity and understanding user requirements.

Comment: Very much agree from first line.

Comment: "You can write great, useful software without understanding basic proof techniques." -- I find that the mindset that has come with being trained in TCS helps a lot with understanding and creating complex systems.

Answer (score 0):

A (probably incomplete but too long for a comment) thought of a student:

I never understood the bad blood between students and the proofs. To me, they are the real essence behind the theorems: a theorem is just a claim, the proof is the reason why that claim is considered a theorem.

Every time I see a proof, I try to understand how the author thinks about that particular topic. Of course, <strike>sometimes</strike> often it can be hard, but the more time you spend on studying proofs the more you learn.

Long story short: the proofs are the difference between science and magic.

---

To answer your question: **yes**, you will see theorems (and their proofs) everywhere during your courses (mathematical sciences are built up theorem by theorem), and **yes**, they will teach you how to reason, and hence you will become a better problem solver.

---

Ironically, the major current challenge in computer science is really about proof: informally, it asks whether *proving* something is more difficult than *checking* the correctness of a proof. Since the answer is believed to be yes, this teach us an important thing: don't just check the proof step-by-step (which is easier) but really try to understand what is going on.